# django -- conditional branch in view.py based on the value obtain by ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

Currently, I made simple application using django and ajax.
Although the code of the structure as below is written,
the value sending with ajax is able to receive in `view.py`.
However, When used the value in a conditional branch after that, I cannot it.
what is the cause of problem?

ajax.html

```
var slot_id = 1;

$.ajax({ 
type:"POST",
data:{
'slot_id':slot_id,
},
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    slot_id = request._post['slot_id']
    print(slot_id) ** it can display 1**

    if slot_id == 1:
        print(slot_id) **it cannot display 1**
```

Comment: check the type of slot_id. You're comparing against an integer and its a string. Possibly?

Comment: @Will is correct.  change to `slot_id = int(request._post['slot_id'])`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think your pointed out is correct, but I do not know how to look up attributes.

Comment: Thank you @HenryM ! I can solve this problem!

Comment: better yet, json.loads ... Ajax gave you JSON encoded data

Comment: @Will, thank you for your advice too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem based on advice.
view.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    slot_id = int(request._post['slot_id'])
    print(slot_id) 

    if slot_id == 1:
        print(slot_id) **it can display 1**
```